# Send data from arduino ble to raspberry pi 2 as serial over bluetooth

Tags: pi-2, bluetooth, arduino, serial-console

Im trying to send data from an arduino with integrated ble (bluno nano from DFRobot) to a raspberry pi 2 which has an hm10 ble module connected to its serial0 gpio14 and 15 pins.  I link the devices by sending AT+CONNmac through a python script.

On the pi with hm10 module Im using this python to read it:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import serial
from time import sleep
ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/serial0',parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,timeout=1)
while 1:
    try:
            sleep(2)
            ser.write("S")
            myData = ser.readline()
            print myData
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
            exit()
```

So far what works is sending data from the bluno nano to the pi and I can see the values coming into the pi terminal from the bluno nano after linking both devices via bluetooth.

```
float flow = 111.22;
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
    }
    void loop() {
      Serial.print(flow);
      Serial.print("\n");
    }
```

What doesnt work is when I try to test what comes into the bluno from the raspberry pi:

```
float flow = 111.22;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()>0) {
    if (Serial.read() == 'S') {
       Serial.print(flow);
       Serial.print("\n");
    }
  }
}
```

and when I simply use a script to send data from the pi to the bluno and have the bluno write it back to the pi, I get a bunch of ????????? on the pi terminal:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  //initial the Serial
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available())  {
    Serial.write(Serial.read());//send what has been received
  }
}
```

I dont understand why I can send data from bluno to pi but not from pi to bluno?  Or maybe data is being sent but not recognized properly by the bluno.